# why String Array did't tak a string as first Index

Tags: java, string, arrays

I have the following code. There is problem in `String[] sep2=strAdder;` compiler suggests that change the sep2 to String or change the type of strAdder to String[]. I am confused about that. I think it should work

```
String strAdder = null;

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null )   {
    if (strLine.contains(">>")) {
        String[] sep1 = strLine.split(">>");
        String[] sep2 = strAdder;
        dd = null;
    }
    if (!(strLine.contains(">>"))) {
        strAdder.concat(strLine.toString());
    }
    i++;
}
in.close();
```

Comment: First of all `sep2` is just a local variable within the scope of that if statement. It's not read, just set, so you might as well just delete that line and get rid of the other problem, which is: `sep2` is a String array, whereas `strAdder` is just a String. Their types are incompatible, that's why you cannot do that assignment in that line. Last but not least, what are you trying to do with strAdder?

Comment: @unluddite then  String[] sep1=strLine.split(">>") why it is working. strLine is a string ,how sep1 take it as first index

Comment: `String.split()` returns a `String[]` type so that's why that's working.

Comment: @ unluddite oh sorry .

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what you are trying to do. `strAdder` is of type `String`, which means you can't assign it to `String[]`.  Given that I don't know what you plan to do with `sep2` then you could do `String sep2 = strAdder` or `String[] sep2 = new String[]{strAdder}`

Comment: I need A String array in witch i want to add stradder.i.e if second if condition becomes true thenstrconcanticante strline every time. but when 1st if condition becomes true then I want to add stradder as first index of sep2. so i need sep2 as a String[].

Answer (score 0):

What is the i++ doing? Apart from that , your second if statement is nothing but the "else" of the previous if.Why have another if for that? strLine is already a String why convert to string.And finally if you want to store just store "String sep2= strAdder;"

Comment: thanks I was applying multiple operations , forget to delete i++. If you take a review of @unluddite point then you come to know what was my error. Thanks for suggestion